# ng-click is not working after updating to iron-router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

We have have been using Angular routes on the client side and server side routes using Router .Now I have updated my application to iron-router on both client and server side.After updating to Iron router angular stuff is broken in my application.

Here is one example:

After updating to iron-router from router the ng-click on the anchor tag is not working.

Template

[image]

Here is the router.

```
Router.route('/login', {
controller: 'LoginController',
action: 'login'
});

Router.route('/home', {
controller: 'HomeController',
action: 'home'
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
onBeforeAction: function () {
console.log('app before hook!');
this.next();
},
action: function () {
console.log('this should be overridden!');
}
});

Router.onAfterAction(function (req, res, next) {
    Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
        angular.element(document).injector().invoke(['$compile', '$document', '$rootScope',
            function ($compile, $document, $rootScope) {
                $compile($document)($rootScope);
                if (!$rootScope.$$phase)
                    $rootScope.$apply();
            }
        ]);
    });
});



LoginController = ApplicationController.extend({
    login: function () {
        this.render('login');
    }
});

HomeController = ApplicationController.extend({
    home: function () {
        this.render('home');
    }
});
```